# Fetch post request not working javascript express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, fetch, body-parser

I am trying to post the data from javascript to the express server using fetch, but the then part in the fetch is not executed and when I console log the req.body in app.js it prints "Body  [object Object]". Please help me fix this fetch.

book.ejs

```
<script> 
 document.getElementsByClassName('submit_booking_btn')[0].addEventListener('submit',function(){
    e.preventDefault();
fetch('/booking', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
   'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
            name: "John",
            email: document.getElementById("myCalendar").value
          })
   }).then(function(response){ return response.json()})
     .then(function(myJson){console.log(myJson);})
     .catch(e=>{console.log(e);})
    })
</script>
```

app.js

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.post("/booking",function(req,res){
  console.log("Body  "+ req.body);
  res.render("home");
});
```

Comment: Because you are concatenating strings when logging req.body, JS actually first converts req,body to string. And if you try to call `toString()` on any object, you will get `[object Object]`

Comment: Try running this: `console.log(req.body)` as well as `console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body))`

Comment: Hey console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body)) worked but i did not get data sent by fetch

Comment: Try removing the Content-Type header, as you are not sending urlencoded data.

Comment: I removed the header part it is still not working

Comment: Hey i found one mistake I missed e as a parameter in "document.getElementsByClassName('submit_booking_btn')[0].addEventListener('submit',function(){". Now I am getting an error "No resource with given URL found"

Comment: You need the `Content-Type` header, but it has to match the type of content (JSON) you are sending.

Comment: U are right @Quentin i used "headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }" and it works now!Thank u

Comment: @code u were right code there was a problem with the header.Thank u!

Comment: @Quentin now the problem is im able to get the data but i get an error "SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0" . Pleease help